# C# Draw Random Rectangles

Tags: c#, timer, drawing, flappy-bird-clone

i wrote a little code like one from Flappy Bird (game) and in one of my timer i wrote the following code but when i'm starting this timer it's just showing me one up and one down pipe 3 times and then the painting just going black and it's showing me no more pipes. If you guys telling me where's the problem, that would be thankful..

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Pipe1[0] + PipeWidth <= 0 | start == true)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int px = this.Width;
            int py = rnd.Next(40, (this.Height - PipeDifferentY));
            var p2x = px;
            var p2y = py + PipeDifferentY;
            int[] p1 = { px, py, p2x, p2y };
            Pipe1 = p1;
        }
        else
        {
            Pipe1[0] = Pipe1[0] - 2;
            Pipe1[2] = Pipe1[2] - 2;
        }
        if (Pipe2[0] + PipeWidth <= 0)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int px = this.Width;
            int py = rnd.Next(40, (this.Height - PipeDifferentY));
            var p2x = px;
            var p2y = py + PipeDifferentY;
            int[] p1 = { px, py, p2x, p2y };
            Pipe1 = p1;
        }
        else
        {
            Pipe2[0] = Pipe2[0] - 2;
            Pipe2[2] = Pipe2[2] - 2;
        }
        if (start == true)
        {
            start = false;
        }
    }
```

And here is the declares:

```
int[] Pipe1 = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int[] Pipe2 = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
int PipeWidth = 55;
int PipeDifferentY = 140;
int PipeDifferentX = 180;
bool start = true;
```

Here is the Load Form part:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int py = rnd.Next(40, (this.Height - PipeDifferentY));
int py2 = py + PipeDifferentY;
int[] p1 = { this.Width, py, this.Width, py2 };
Pipe1 = p1;

py = rnd.Next(40, (this.Height - PipeDifferentY));
py2 = py + PipeDifferentY;
int[] p2 = { this.Width + PipeDifferentX, py, this.Width + PipeDifferentX, py2 };
Pipe2 = p2;
```

Here is the painting part:

```
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightCyan, new Rectangle(Pipe1[0], 0, PipeWidth, Pipe1[1]));
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightCyan, new Rectangle(Pipe1[2], Pipe1[3], PipeWidth, this.Height - Pipe1[3]));

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightCyan, new Rectangle(Pipe2[0], 0, PipeWidth, Pipe2[1]));
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightCyan, new Rectangle(Pipe2[2], Pipe2[3], PipeWidth, this.Height - Pipe2[3]));
```

And the first timer has just:

```
this.Invalidate();
```

Comment: This is maybe not related to your problem, but you should make the `Random` object a field in your class and create it in the constructor. Do not create it in the timer handler. Otherwise it might keep producing the same value if the timer tick interval is very short.

Comment: No is still doing that.., can you show me how by code?

Comment: It's a bit hard to see what might be wrong from just this code. One other unrelated thing though: You seem to be using `dynamic` where you should be using `var`.

Comment: But it's keep giving me the same 'error' with 'var' too

Comment: Yes, that's unrelated, but you shouldn't be using `dynamic` instead of `var`.

Comment: oke, please look down what i commented to Starscream1984, if you can help me with it.

Comment: Here's my suggestion: Take that code and put it into a Console test app and call it from a loop rather than a timer. Then you'll be able to run it under the debugger and see what's going wrong.

Comment: Hey Matthew, but i have this at the beggining: int[] Pipe1 = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }; and i made that int[] p1 with those values, because i couln't put it dirrectly into Pipe1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a stray `Pipe1` at the bottom of your `Pipe2` if statement.

Update:

Try change declares to:

```
List<int> Pipe1 = new List<int>();
List<int> Pipe2 = new List<int>();
int PipeWidth = 55;
int PipeDifferentY = 140;
int PipeDifferentX = 180;
bool start = true;
```

and timer function to:

```
 private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Pipe1[0] + PipeWidth <= 0 | start == true)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int px = this.Width;
                int py = rnd.Next(40, (this.Height - PipeDifferentY));
                var p2x = px;
                var p2y = py + PipeDifferentY;
                Pipe1.Clear();
                Pipe1.Add(px);
                Pipe1.Add(py);
                Pipe1.Add(p2x);
                Pipe1.Add(p2y);
            }
            else
            {
                Pipe1[0] = Pipe1[0] - 2;
                Pipe1[2] = Pipe1[2] - 2;
            }
            if (Pipe2[0] + PipeWidth <= 0)
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                int px = this.Width;
                int py = rnd.Next(40, (this.Height - PipeDifferentY));
                var p2x = px;
                var p2y = py + PipeDifferentY;
                int[] p1 = { px, py, p2x, p2y };
                Pipe2.Clear();
                Pipe2.Add(px);
                Pipe2.Add(py);
                Pipe2.Add(p2x);
                Pipe2.Add(p2y);
            }
            else
            {
                Pipe2[0] = Pipe2[0] - 2;
                Pipe2[2] = Pipe2[2] - 2;
            }
            if (start == true)
            {
                start = false;
            }
        }
```

and your load form part:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int py = rnd.Next(40, (this.Height - PipeDifferentY));
int py2 = py + PipeDifferentY;
Pipe1.Clear();
Pipe1.Add(this.Width);
Pipe1.Add(py);
Pipe1.Add(this.Width);
Pipe1.Add(p2y);

py = rnd.Next(40, (this.Height - PipeDifferentY));
py2 = py + PipeDifferentY;
Pipe2.Clear();
Pipe2.Add(this.Width + PipeDifferentX);
Pipe2.Add(py);
Pipe2.Add(this.Width + PipeDifferentX);
Pipe2.Add(p2y);
```

painting part should be ok

Comment: yes because i gave to pipe1, which is a int array, that new value from p1, cus i couldn't give it to it easier.

Comment: any help resolving this?

Comment: i have this at the beggining: int[] Pipe1 = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };  and i made that int[] p1 with those values, because i couln't put it dirrectly into Pipe1

Comment: Can you tell me how to put directly values to that int[] Pipe1 ?

Comment: You could probably use a generic list instead of array for adding values directly on the fly: `List<int> Pipe1 as new List<int>;`

Comment: and then `Pipe1.Add(x1)` etc and you can still refer to them by index for getting later like `Pipe1[0]`

Comment: I don't really understand what the Pipe2 array is for when you put into Pipe1 array both times.

Comment: Hey but it won't work like that, because i have to specify into the New Rectangle(...) the x and y from Pipe1 which are Pipe[0] and Pipe[2]

Comment: Why can't you do that, it should work fine? `new Rectangle(Pipe1[0], Pipe1[1], Pipe1[2], Pipe1[3])`

Comment: i tried but i didn't work like that, take a look now to my code, i put it all, maybe now can you understand more.

Comment: Starscream, can you know be more clearly? I really need to finish this..help me

Comment: It' giving me a huge white and red crossed X, maybe i need to change something in Form_Load too, do i?

Comment: It's working very good, many thanks Starscream1984. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, I think even without the changing of array to list, your main problem was assigning values meant for Pipe2 into Pipe1 by mistake.